# Coordinate projection transformation Mars image from Ocentric Equirectangular to Transverse Mercator in Python

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp, mars

The task is to re-project the Mars image from Ocentric Equirectangular projection to Transverse Mercator.

I'm trying to do this in gdal in python.

In terms of Transverse Mercator projection, there is no default model in gdal.
So, I customize the Transverse Mercator projection of Mars in WKT format as below.
But syntax error, "invalid syntax" has came up for "PROJECTION" parameter.

I think "PROJECTION" is an appropriate parameter.
What should I do for solving this problem.

---

```
output_proj = PROJCS["Transverse Mercator Mars",
                GEOGCS["GCS_MARS", 
                    DATUM["Custom_Mars_Datum",
                        ELLIPSOID["Custom_Mars_Ellipsoid", 3396190.0, 169.894447224]
                        ],
                    PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian", 0.0] 
                        ]
                PROJECTION["Transverse Mercator Mars"], 
                PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0, 
                    ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]　
                PARAMETER["longitude_of_origin", 0, 
                    ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]] 
                PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0] 
                PARAMETER["false_northing", 0, 
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]] 
                PARAMETER["false_easting", 0, 
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]] 
                　　　　]
```

### gdalwarp -s_srs Mars_2015_Ocentric_Equirectangular_clon_0 -t_srs Transverse Mercator Mars input_file output_file

[image]